# i want to search and display the data from database but it gives me error

Tags: php, html

this is my search_candidate.php file

```
<?php

   $name = $_GET['name'];
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE Name = $name";
   $query = mysql_query( $sql );
          if(mysql_num_rows($query) == "")
          {
          echo "no result found";
          }
          echo "<table>";

          echo "<thead></thead>";
                while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $query ) )
                     {
                      echo "<tr></tr>";
                     }
          echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any syntex error?

Comment: `$query = mysql_query( $sql ) or die(mysql_error());` and see the error you're not checking for.

Comment: **Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).** They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). **Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)** instead, and **use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo).** **[DANGER! You need to prevent SQL Injection!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)**

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE Name = $name
```

`$name` is a string and needs to be in quotes like `'$name'`

But even after that fix you wont get anything because your loop doesnt print any data. It just opens and closes new rows without anything inside.

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code it will work.

```
<?php

   $name = $_GET['name'];
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE Name = '$name'";
   $query = mysql_query( $sql );
          if(mysql_num_rows($query) == "")
          {
          echo "no result found";
          }
          echo "<table>";

          echo "<thead></thead>";
                while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $query ) )
                     {
                      echo "<tr><td>".$row['name']."</td></tr>";
                     }
          echo "</table>";
?>
```

Copied code from question and make changes on 2 errors `$name` string must be in quotes and added `<td>".$row['name']."</td>` in your loop to show something.

Your code allow any one to inject so try to use [PDO](http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-use-pdo-database-connection-in-php_461.html) or [MySQLi](http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-use-mysqli_connect-in-php_336.html) connection.

Comment: @Fred-ii- People don't like help so..

Comment: I know the feeling. Must be having bad coffee.

Comment: @HuzoorBux Maybe you can also highlight where the error is and explain why you have to put `$name` in quotes, also don't understand how downvoted this

Comment: @Rizier123 you are right my mistake.

Comment: Please don't be judgmental about down-votes so fast. I'll tell you why this was down-voted. This answer took the pain to copy paste code from question and fix one string quotation mark and failed to realize that rest of the pasted code is still wrong, it doesn't output any data. All what this loop does is `echo "<tr></tr>";`  Does that produce the output? Why reproduce wrong code?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky True true, but the fix is still partially there. OP needs to fix it and here too, but I agree. I hadn't noticed that originally.

Comment: Now that we know the reason, i'll retract the down-vote.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Thanks for pointing me i have fixed that error and add some more explanation in it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems name is string so add a quote to `$name` in query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE Name = '$name'";
```

**Note** :- `mysql_*` has been deprecated use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.